# Is there a way to make 3D histograms using Paraview or Visit?

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have a rectangular grid with sparse cell values? Is there a way i can make a 3D histogram because the grid is so large that these cells appear as points and are not visible?

Answer (score 2):

ParaView doesn't support 3D histograms (at least as of version 4.0.1).